# MATLAB script runs slowly: Solving System of Equations

Tags: matlab

**EDIT:** I used the profiler as suggested, and it looks like Matlab was spending a significant amount of time dealing with symbols and solving the system of equations. So, I will change my question slightly: is there a faster way to implement this system of equations, perhaps one that does not involve declaring symbols?

```
function [As_rad, Ae_rad] = pos_to_angle(x_pos, y_pos)
    % Converts given x and y coordinates into angles (using link lengths)

    Ls = 0.4064;   % in meters
    Le = 0.51435;  % in meters
    x_offset = 0.0;
    y_offset = -0.65;   % from computer running the robot

    syms angle_s angle_e

    x = x_pos + x_offset;       % Account for offset of origins
    y = y_pos + y_offset;       % between motor and workspace

    eqn1 = x == Ls*cos(angle_s) + Le*cos(angle_e);  % Actual conversion
    eqn2 = y == Ls*sin(angle_s) + Le*sin(angle_e);
    sol1 = solve([eqn1, eqn2], [angle_s, angle_e]);
    As_rad_mat = sol1.angle_s;
    Ae_rad_mat = sol1.angle_e;

    if As_rad_mat(1) > Ae_rad_mat(1);
        As_rad = As_rad_mat(1);
        Ae_rad = Ae_rad_mat(1);
    else
        As_rad = As_rad_mat(2);
        Ae_rad = Ae_rad_mat(2);
    end
end
```

To be more specific, it looked like a function mupadmex (which I believe is associated with symbols) took up about 80% of the computing time. The above is just an example of how I solved systems of equations throughout the script.

Comment: [Profile your code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html)

Comment: The main functions in your `for` loop we do not have access to, so there is absolutely no way we can figure out why it's getting progressively slower at each iteration of your code. The problem is obviously something that is contained within the functions themselves. Either show us the code for each function, or as what excaza mentioned... profile your code.

Comment: What you are solving is a non-linear system of equations as the variables to solve are arguments into non-linear functions.  `solve` is pretty much the only way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the responses! I ended up using profiler and found that the computation time was coming from solving the system of equations every time the program went through the loop. So I used a separate script to solve for the equation symbolically, so the script only has to do algebra. It is running MUCH quicker now.